# Visual Studio 2022 cshtml Code Formatting problem

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-2022

I have problem in code formatting (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) in cshtml file. When I press on shortcuts, brackets and some script are going in a wrong place:

```
        IsAutoLoad = true,
        Ordering = false,
        Columns = new List<ColumnModel>
{
new ColumnModel { title = "Type", data = "ClientType", columnNumber = 1 },
new ColumnModel { title = "Full Name", data = "FullName", columnNumber = 2 },
new ColumnModel { title = "PIN", data = "PersonalNumber", columnNumber = 3 },
new ColumnModel { title = "Doc Type", data = "AgreementDescription", columnNumber = 4 },
new ColumnModel { title = "", onClickFunction = "OnPrintDocFunc", columnNumber = 5, columnType = ColumnTypes.Pdf }
},
        Paging = false
```

I have spaces in all languages for spacing (not tabs).

-- I found similar problem on stackoverflow, but it's old and on older version of VS.